# I have 2 new users who have the same privileges, should I assign them the same UID or not and why?

Tags: permissions, uid

I have 2 new users, Jack and Annie, they have the same privileges, should I assign them the same UID or not and why?

[image]

Comment: no each user has a unique UID

Comment: You may add them to the same **group** if they should have the same privileges, and control the permissions on group level - this is how it's usually done.

Answer (score 4):

User names and UID are unique identifiers for the users registered on the system. Assigning them a same UID is not an option.

Comment: You ***can*** have two users with the _same user id_ by manually editing `/etc/passwd` file, but of course this is not a wise thing to do...